# Adding cb_admin to current ChicagoBoss installation

Tags: git, erlang, erlang-shell, erl, chicagoboss

I'm starting with `ChicagoBoss` as well

I just installed `ChicagoBoss` following the github instructions.

Then, I created a project:

```
make
make app PROJECT=myproject
cd ../myproject
```

Everything's cool so far, now, I want to add the [admin interface](https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/cb_admin) such as `cb_admin`, so I add to `myproject` rebar.conf this line `{cb_admin, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/ChicagoBoss/cb_admin.git", "HEAD"}}` so it will become:

```
{deps, [
    {boss, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss.git", {tag, "v0.9.beta-1"}}}
    {cb_admin, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/ChicagoBoss/cb_admin.git", "HEAD"}}
]}.
{plugin_dir, ["priv/rebar"]}.
{plugins, [boss_plugin]}.
{eunit_compile_opts, [{src_dirs, ["src/test"]}]}.
{lib_dirs, ["../ChicagoBoss/deps/elixir/lib"]}.
```

So I run `./rebar get-deps compile`, but it keeps throwing me this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to load /home/kristian/erlang-projects/myproject /rebar.config: {error,
                                                                             {3,
                                                                             erl_parse,
                                                                             ["syntax error before: ",
                                                                             "'{'"]}}
```

Please, anybody has an idea about this?

My erlang version is `19`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing a comma (,) after your

```
{boss, ".*", {git, "https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/ChicagoBoss.git", {tag, "v0.9.beta-1"}}}
```

your error message indicates a syntax error on line 3, and I can see there is no comma between these two dependencies.